# Get AWS ECS Task Description Tags in PHP Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have dockerized Laravel application on AWS ECR/ECS using Fargate Task Definition. I have set some tag/value pairs in the Task Definition (ex: RDS_HOST, RDS_USER, RDS_PASS). And I want Laravel inside the running Task (Container) to access and use these values as regular environment variables. How can I do this?

I have also setup and configured `aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel`.

---

I could hardcode the vars in the .env but that's not practical. Vars have to be in declared in the Task Definition as Tag/Value pairs.

Comment: So, your issue is that you have no idea how to make `RDS_HOST` and all the others be set in the Laravel's machine as an environment variable?

Comment: Exactly, while Laravel is being run inside a container.

Comment: I could hardcode the vars in the `.env` but that's not practical. Vars have to be in declared in the Task Definition as Tag/Value pairs.

Comment: How are you defining your  tasks? If you're doing it manually via the web interface then there's not much you can do. I suggest using something like the docker compose ecs plugin or a cloudformation template, that way you can define the tags and environment variables within your container definition using some shared variable from outside

Comment: I was just wondering if there's any way I can get the values of AWS Tags via PHP SDK.

Comment: Tags are the wrong way to do this, especially for secrets like your RDS password. Tags are not secure. You should be setting things like `RDS_HOST` and `RDS_USER` in the task's environment variables, and `RDS_PASS` in the tasks secrets. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-data-security-container-task/#:~:text=Reference%20sensitive%20information%20in%20the%20ECS%20task%20definition,register%20the%20task%20definition%2C%20run%20the%20following%20command%3A